# Javaのオブジェクトを漢字の読みのあいうえお順でソートしたい

Tags: java

下記ソースを実行してみましたが漢字の昇順ソートがうまくいっていません。（実行結果として高橋達也が桜木満よりも先に表示されてしまう)。上手くソートされるようにするためにはソースをどう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。
実行結果は下記となります。
安藤純一,27,m,164
井上直美,24,f,158
榎本タスク,24,m,178
榎本恵,24,f,162
高橋達也,23,m,176
桜木満,26,f,163

```
public class SmartEnergy {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        students.add(new Student("井上直美", 24, 'f', 158));
        students.add(new Student("高橋達也", 23, 'm', 176));
        students.add(new Student("安藤純一", 27, 'm', 164));
        students.add(new Student("榎本恵", 24, 'f', 162));
        students.add(new Student("榎本タスク", 24, 'm', 178));
        students.add(new Student("桜木満", 26, 'f', 163));

        Collections.sort(students, new Comparator<Student>() {
            public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
                final Collator japanCollation =Collator.getInstance( Locale.JAPANESE );
                int temp = 0;
                temp = japanCollation.compare(student1.getName(),student2.getName());
                return temp;
            }
        });

        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student.getName() + "," + student.getAge() + ","
                    + student.getSex() + "," + student.getHeight());
        }
```

Comment: よみがなのフィールドを作成してそれを使う様に変更してみたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: なぜこれが「上手くソート」できていないのでしょうか？あなたしか知り得ない暗黙の過程を置いていませんか？

Comment: あいうえお順のソート（昇順ソート）を想定しているのにソート後、高橋達也（たかはしたつや）が桜木満（さくらぎみつる）より先にＬｉｓｔの要素として保持されているのでうまくソートされていないと判断しました。
よみがなのフィールドを作成してそれを使う様にソースを変更してみたら期待どおりのものが出来ました。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

よみがなのフィールドを作成してそれを使う様に変更してみたらどうでしょうか？

漢字を元にソートしてしまうと、たとえば「河野（かわの）」と「河野（こうの）」の区別ができないなどの根本的な問題があります。

<sub>-- [BLUEPIXYさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/5044/bluepixy)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34482/java%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AA%E3%83%96%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E6%BC%A2%E5%AD%97%E3%81%AE%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%88%E3%81%8A%E9%A0%86%E3%81%A7%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84#comment34229_34482)に少し追記しました。</sub>